# RW access to shared Windows folder using different user credentials in .NET

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, active-directory, impersonation

We are working in Windows network (AD in use)
We have folder shared by user (access limited for this user only) User credentials are known 
I need to access to that share inside my app.

Note I've read about **Impersonation** but what I can do is open entire application in new user context (but what I need is working as currently logged user, just access to Windows' shared folder in behalf on another user)

Would it be possible? Piece of code appreciated..

Comment: Have you had any luck figuring this out?

Comment: Yeah I did it. Please look my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've finally managed that and works as a harm to  me!.
For those interested - please find sample method doing the job (note you need System.Security.Principal + Interop, also some API static methods need to be added )

```
    public const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
    public const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;

    public bool ImpersonateUser( string userName, string domain, string password ) {
        WindowsIdentity tempWindowsIdentity;
        IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr tokenDuplicate = IntPtr.Zero;

        if (RevertToSelf ()) {
            if (LogonUserA ( userName, domain, password, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
                LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref token ) != 0) {
                if (DuplicateToken ( token, 2, ref tokenDuplicate ) != 0) {
                    tempWindowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity ( tokenDuplicate );
                    impersonationContext = tempWindowsIdentity.Impersonate ();
                    if (impersonationContext != null) {
                        CloseHandle ( token );
                        CloseHandle ( tokenDuplicate );
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (token!= IntPtr.Zero)
            CloseHandle ( token );
        if (tokenDuplicate!=IntPtr.Zero)
            CloseHandle ( tokenDuplicate );
        return false;
    }
```